Philosophical system
I want to build a philosophical system and describe a certain process. The system has x number of axioms. I can translate the axioms into predicates and quantifiers or into Boolean form. My question is the following: how optimal is it to use such a method for creating a philosophical system, since the number of theorems will be in the hundreds, which in turn will allow for the derivation of an infinite number of theorems?

Impossible task :-) the issue is not the number of theorem, but the huge number of axioms and initial definitions needed.

Having said that, IF you have: a) the list of undefined terms; b) the list of axioms (that must use only the basic terms); c) the list of definitions (of new terms in term of basic ones), the task of formalization using predicate logic is straightforward.

@NemesisTS Possibly one should do it the other way round: First building an interesting theory and then axiomatizing the theory. - What is an interesting theory? It should explain an important  process which otherwise is not understood.

Re the tag "formal system": a formal system is uninterpreted; how can you think to develop an uninterpreted philosophical system?

How familiar are you with symbolic logic?  Like a foreign language or musical notation, the novice may find it tedious and painstaking to read and write, but those with many years of experience become fluent.  If you are fluent in symbolic logic then I suspect that you will find the process efficient, because the proofs are much easier to check.  If you are not fluent then you may find yourself translating back-and-forth to the vernacular for every little thing, which will prove tiresome and feel pointless.

@MauroALLEGRANZA It's my edit. Formal systems aren't strings of characters selected at random; they represent a complex of concepts. That correspondence between the formal syntax and the natural language which serves as the basis of the implementation of a formal system are paired such as the former is a linguistic metalanguage the latter is the symbolic object language. But formal systems themselves also have a semantics regarding the syntax itself. For instance, in Zalta's Principia, he spends Chapter 7 providing definitions of formal syntax.

While the automation and execution of a formal system can arguably be uninterpreted, isn't it a necessary condition of a formal system that it is built from at least one interpretation?

@MauroALLEGRANZA, It's more accurate to say that the term "formal system" has two meanings that are close enough to be confusing in some cases. It can refer to what you suggest: an uninterpreted term rewriting system, but it can also refer to a system of logic with a calculus and an interpretation.

Constructing formal systems for reasoning about certain topics in philosophy is common, useful, allows for precision about the difficult and subtle points in the theory, and is a good idea.
It is not a problem for the number of theorems to be infinite, since you're not about to go writing down every theorem in the system. Presumably you would only write down the theorems that are relevant to discussion of whatever particular philosophical problem you are trying to investigate. The same is true in mathematics: of course there are infinitely many theorems in the usual foundations of mathematics, but the business of mathematicians isn't to write down every single theorem (impossible, and useless!), but rather to work out and write down specifically those theorems which settle particular, well-motivated problems.
Here are some examples of books and papers which offer well-constructed formal systems for reasoning about particular topics in philosophy, which maybe you would find useful to look at:

Zalta "Abstract Objects: an Introduction to Axiomatic Metaphysics" (1983) and Zalta "Principia Logico-Metaphysica" (in progress, available online)

Meixner "Axiomatic Formal Ontology" (1997)

Bealer "Quality and Concept" (1982)

Bacon "Logical Combinatorialism" (2020) and Bacon "Substitution Structures" (2019)

Dorr "To be F is to be G" (2016)

Any book on modal logic which explains the relevance to philosophy. My favorite is Fitting and Mendelsohn "First-order Modal Logic" (1998)

Most of those are about metaphysics and logic. For a nice example from epistemology, Hintikka "Knowledge and Belief" (1962)


Lots of other examples exist! These are just a few that come to mind because I enjoyed each of them very much.


how optimal is it to use such a method for creating a philosophical system

It depends on what your topic is, how you plan to go about it, and also whether you have an understanding of what constitutes a rigorous mathematical proof. It could go one of two ways:

You could have rigorously logical things to say about a domain that is essentially mathematical. Probability, physics, modal logic, semantics - that kind of thing. This may turn out well.
You could make unclear claims in natural language, and write them with mathematical and logical symbols as if they were absolute laws. This would reflect a fundamental misunderstanding about thinking and deduction and is doomed. I've seen crackpots try this.

Most of human thinking is not deduction. Human thinking is fuzzy, approximate, and heuristic, and these qualities are what make it so powerful at dealing with the world. We cannot, for instance, logically deduce that if you turn an open-topped bucket of liquid water upside down, it will pour out. There are many unusual conditions under which it would not.
Deduction is a powerful tool as well, but it needs to be applied in an appropriate domain where we can make deductions of logical necessity.

+1 "I've seen crackpots try this." Many crackpots! However, user509184 put a link to Zalta's Principia, and I can't help but wonder how the general editor of the SEP and noted philosopher of Stanford could, based on reputation, be characterized as a crackpot. @KristianBerry would you be willing to read it and explain Zalta's work to me, ; )


@NemesisTS Possibly one should do it the other way round: First building an interesting theory and then axiomatizing the theory. - What is an interesting theory? It should explain an important process which otherwise is not understood - Jo Wehler

This is indeed how it's done. Nobody thinking in formal languages with ease. Generally, you have an interest in a topic in mathematics, logic, language, or computation, and then when you have an understanding of it, try to codify afterwards. Today, if you go through the hassle of building a system, thinkers are generally likely to formalize the notation.
I'm not sure there is such thing as a canonical "philosophical system"; what there is, however, is a formal system, which is what you are describing. Essentially, a system of symbols that represent propositions is developed that allows for the automation of manipulating. One discipline, linguistic formal semantics studies the use of formal systems across logic, mathematics, linguistics, and computer science, and was inspired by the work of Richard Montague (SEP). This use of technical language tends to inhere most strongly to the techniques of the tradition called analytical philosophy because originates out of the work and interests of Gottlob Frege (SEP) and his program of logicism.
Well designed formal systems have the advantage that they are effectively computable and assist in provability. This is why in the modern age, mathematics, logic, natural language, and programs are all done on electromechanical computers. Automated theorem provers, logic engines, natural language processing, and software more generally are built out and executed because there is a close relation between the languages of mathematics, logic, and software, a result known as the Curry-Howard correspondence.
What formal semantics require, however, are interpretations. For instance if you craft a logic system, then your logic system requires a interpretation of the logic. This is essentially a description of what the symbols mean. One of the most important historical examples of interpretation of a system is the long quest to understand the parallel postulate in Euclid's Elements. Interpreting the postulate in different ways gives rise to non-Euclidean geometries.
It's is this act of interpretation of various systems and theories, be they FOL, QM, ZFC, BNG, HPSG, or PA that is philosophical in nature, because this act of building systems is best accomplished still with human intuition. Once philosophers of math, language, science, and logic begin wrestling over the question of what do the natural language descriptions of the formal theories mean, you've entered philosophical territory. Generally, mathematicians or linguistics, don't delve to deeply into the philosophy, but when they do, the problems get escalated to conflicts of the nature of metaphysical grounding (SEP) and metaphysical explanation (SEP).
If you're interested in seeing the range of building systems, I would recommend three books:

Formal Semantics (GB): An Introduction by Ronnie Cann which is dated by thorough and delves into formal systems across the various disciplines and how they reflect properties of language.
Computability and Logic by Boolos et al. (GB): This takes a through look at ennumerability, arithmetic, FOL, Turing machines, recursion, models, and so on.
Truth & Meaning by Kenneth Taylor (GB): This introduces the work of Frege and Russell Tarskian truth semantics, intensional semantics, introduces some modeling of pragmatics.

These are NOT easy books, and it would be the coup if you could read and understand all of them. But about 95% of what you'll come across on this site in formalisms is covered by the ideas in these books. Formal systems really is a rabbit hole of detail and is more an attitude and approach to doing philosophy then it is anyone discipline. And all of this work generally traces its heritage back to Frege's Begriffsschrift and his philosophical work with mathematics and logic. Today, all sorts of formal systems play a role in the advancement of computers and the expanding frontier of GOFAI, data science, and machine learning.
